# template aliases and sfinae

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, template-aliases

In the case of a substitution failure involving a template alias (*e.g.* a template alias on a missing member typename, as in the code snippet below), should an error be triggered ?

Clang and gcc seem to disagree on this:

```cxx
// some types
struct bar { };

struct foo {
    typedef void member_type;
};


// template alias
template<class T>
using member = typename T::member_type;


template<class T>
void baz(... ) { }

// only works for gcc, clang fails with: no type named 'member_type'
// in 'bar'
template<class T>
void baz( member<T>* ) { }


int main(int, char** ) {

    baz<bar>(0);            // picks first
    baz<foo>(0);            // picks second

    return 0;
}
```

So the question is: who is correct, and why ?

Thanks :-)

Comment: What does `clang -v` say? Clang 3.3 trunk compiles the code just fine.

Comment: Debian clang version 3.1-8 here, looks like I just need to wait. Thanks for your feedback !

Comment: Can you get rid of the template alias, just to simplify things a little

Comment: @Dave: The whole point of the question was about using aliases, so...

Comment: @Xeo oh, sorry. I only looked at the code and thought it was just about SFINAE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Standards, it is clearly GCC that is correct, because the alias template must immediately be replaced and then normal/usual SFINAE is applied to `typename T::member_type` later when `T` is known.

But there currently is an issue for this, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1554.

According to the meetings outcome, it appears that clangs behavior is desired: The substitution of `T` will be done in the context of the alias template (even though at the time of substitution in `typename T::member_type`, there is no reference to the alias template anymore - it will still need to be referenced as the source of where the parameter type pattern originated from, if this is how it's implemented).

---

This is similar to another situation where patterns are thrown away on definition time that could influence instantiation semantics

```
template<int I>
void f(int x[I]);

int main() {
  f<0>(nullptr);
}
```

In this case too, in my opinion the Standard normatively is clear that the parameter is immediately being replaced by `int*` and thus the instantiation works. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1322 .

Comment: "According to the meetings outcome, it appears that clangs behavior is desired" -- wouldn't this totally kill any `EnableIf` alias out there? It *seems* highly undesirable to have alias templates not generate SFINAE soft-errors.

Comment: @Xeo yes that would be bad. And in fact, clang trunk accepts the `EnableIf` alias, so it appears to me the behavior that the asker observed was just a clang bug, and that the issue's summary on the wg21 site is just confusing (IMHO).

Comment: Yeah, I was confused since I already commented that the trunk compiles the code fine.