# Template constraints on operator overloading does not work as expected

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++20, c++-concepts

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct is_tuple_like : std::false_type {};

template<typename... Ts>
struct is_tuple_like<std::tuple<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_tuple_like<std::pair<T, U>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
concept tuple_like = is_tuple_like<T>::value;

template<tuple_like L, tuple_like R, int N = std::tuple_size_v<L>>
auto operator*(const L &lhs, const R &rhs) { return 0; }

enum { Enum };

int main()
{
    Enum * Enum; // causes compilation error
    return 0;
}
```

You can run the code here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f65e333060f40e60

I have defined a concept so-called `tuple_like` and overloaded `operator*()` using the concept.

Then, If I multiply `enum`s, my overloaded `operator*()` for `tuple_like` is picked up and the compiler complains missing `std::tuple_size` for `enum`.

What did I do wrong here and how can I fix it without overload for each class templates - `std::tuple` and `std::pair`?

FYI, even if it's unusual, I cannot remove the part of multiplying `enum`s because it's not my code.

Comment: What's `int N` for?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13730889/27678 https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1554 and https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1844 Basically the question is how template aliases participate in SFINAE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn `tuple_size_v` into `tuple_size::value` to enable SFINAE

```
template<tuple_like L, tuple_like R, int N = std::tuple_size<L>::value>
auto operator*(const L &lhs, const R &rhs) { return 0; }
```

However, I don't see any value in declaring an extra template parameter `N` here. The type that satisfies `tuple_like` already guarantees that `tuple_size_v` is a valid value.

It would be more appropriate to move `N` into the function body

```
template<tuple_like L, tuple_like R>
auto operator*(const L &lhs, const R &rhs) { 
  constexpr auto N = std::tuple_size_v<L>; // guaranteed to work
  // uses N below
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like gcc can't handle SFINAE for default values of template arguments. This workaround fixes it:

```
template<tuple_like L, tuple_like R, int N>
auto operator*(const L &lhs, const R &rhs) { return 0; }

template<tuple_like L, tuple_like R>
auto operator*(const L &lhs, const R &rhs) { return operator*<L, R, std::tuple_size_v<L>>(lhs, rhs); }
```